# What is the best method for record finding in big MySQL tables?

Tags: mysql, database

I've been thinking lately, but was unable to find any info, which method is the best for records finding in big databases - especially MySQL databases.

Let say I have DB with tables:

- topics: [ID topic, name];
- books: [ID book, ID user, ID topic, title];

The user has some ID which I can use to get all of his books. However, my user wants to know his books by title only in given topic.

So I need to search basing on 2 indexes - ID topic and ID user.

Table topics can have <10 records, while on the other hand table books can have >10 000 records.

My idea is, that the fastest way to get all books requested by user I need to make:

```
 SELECT books.title FROM books WHERE books.ID_topic = idTopic
 AND books.ID_user = idUser ORDER BY topics.ID_topic
```

What is your opinion, is it the best and most efficient way to get data in such case?

**EDIT**

I made a huge mistake in SELECT, thank you for pointing that out.

Answering your questions:

- User can have around 10 books, and 8 can be in category with id 1 and  remaining 2 in the last category.
- By best I mean the fastest in execution

Comment: That query isn't valid. Do you mean to express that as a `JOIN`?

Comment: I'd stick with `select`. Join as needed. That's the usual approach. Why are you particularly concerned about runtime efficiency? Or by "efficient" do you mean "idiomatic"? What are your criteria for "best"?

Comment: do you mean `SELECT title FROM books WHERE ID_topic = ? AND ID_user = ? ORDER BY ID_topic`, where the ? are to be replaced with constants?

Comment: How many books will a user have?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're concerned about speed, there's a very good chance you needn't be. Unless `books` is quite large, even a naive algorithm will search it fast enough for you, and any decent RDBMS will be better than naive. What an experienced professional would do, if he's not dealing with Google/NSA-scaled continents of data, is pick a good database engine, index the tables properly, and let the RDBMS do its job.

That having been said, let's veer off topic: Your table design looks a little weird. What if two users own copies of the same book? What if it's a library with two copies of *Catcher in the Rye* or some godawful nonsense?

You want to have a `book` table, a `user` table, and then a `userbook` table that links the two as appropriate:

```
create table userbook (
    book_id int not null references book(book_id),
    user_id int not null references user(user_id)
)

select user.name
from 
    book b 
    inner join userbook ub
        on ub.book_id = b.book_id
    inner join user u
        on u.user_id = ub.user_id
    where
        book.title = 'It''s the Kali Yuga, Charlie Brown!'
        or book.topic = 'nihilism';
```

Of course, you'd want an author table too, and so on, in a finished design for serious use. But this is the way to think about these things: If a relationship is potentially many to many, that relationship is best expressed as a link table.

Answer (score 2):

It is not 100% clear what you ask, but here is my guess:

1. I would suggest an Index on the books table: `ALTER TABLE books ADD INDEX (ID_user, ID_topic)`
2. Query the table like this: `SELECT books.title FROM books WHERE books.ID_topic = idTopic AND books.ID_user = idUser`. For this to work you need to know the user id and topic id of course. If you want to query by topic name you need a JOIN

Comment: You are right with 2 point. I've made a mistake and already corrected it.